# Chrome extension working with DOM

Tags: dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can i simulate event submit/click on page elements uses chrome plugin?
If plugin mode on. Plugin looking some elements on page and send click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating a custom event from a content script. Try something like this:

```
function simulateClick(elementId) {
  var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, false,  document, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, 
      false, false, false, 0, null);
  document.getElementById(elementId).dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

See [dispatchEvent docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) for more info.

Comment: Wanted to add that it would only trigger `click` event listener function, if there is one. It won't be a true click emulation (you can't programmatically click a link this way for example).

Comment: Is this allowing a google chrome extension JavaScript script to perform a click rather than an actual user?  I'm trying to figure out how this can be used.